# Roslyn: How to add generic class to inherited base list if not already inheriting from class?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a command line application where I start with some string input and I am trying add a base class to all classes that implement a certain interface.

I've gotten to the part where I have the class and checking the base list. But I'm not sure how to

1) Check to make sure the class isn't already inheriting from another class (in that case do nothing).

2) Add the supplied class from the command line to be inherited by the class in question.

So as an example, say I entered:

> -addBaseClass Repository<*PocoClass*,*PocoClass*Table> -interface IUserRepository

This would match my class declaration:

```
internal class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
```

Now I want it to be like this:

```
internal class UserRepository : Repository<User, UserTable>, IUserRepository
{
```

I get the file for the matching class and load that into Roslyn:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                syntaxTree = 
  CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(SourceText.From(stream), path: filePath);
            }

            var root = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
            //get the initial class declaration
            var classDeclaraction = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
            var baseList = classDeclaraction?.BaseList;
```

Thanks to SLaks comment I was able to figure out how to add to the base list:

```
var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax) syntaxTree.GetRoot();
            var classDeclaration = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
            var baseList = classDeclaration?.BaseList;

            var newList = classDeclaration.BaseList.Types.Insert(0, SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(
                SyntaxFactory.GenericName(
                        SyntaxFactory.Identifier(baseClass))
                    .WithTypeArgumentList(
                        SyntaxFactory.TypeArgumentList(
                            SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList<TypeSyntax>(GetGenericParameterSyntaxNode(genericParameters))))).NormalizeWhitespace());
            var modifierList = classDeclaration.Modifiers.Replace(classDeclaration.Modifiers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Kind() == SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword), SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.InternalKeyword));
            var newDeclaration = classDeclaration.WithModifiers(modifierList).WithBaseList(SyntaxFactory.BaseList(newList)).NormalizeWhitespace();

            var newDeclarationRoot = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit()
                .WithMembers(SyntaxFactory.SingletonList<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(newDeclaration)).NormalizeWhitespace();
            var updatedRoot = root.ReplaceNode(root.FindNode(classDeclaration.Span), newDeclarationRoot.FindNode(newDeclaration.Span)).NormalizeWhitespace();
```

So I am generating the file off the updatedRoot now fine. But still not sure how I can check to see if the class already inherits from a class. The BaseList includes interfaces and inherited classes and I can't seem to find anything in the object graph to differentiate.

Comment: You should create tokens for the class & parameters, not assemble a string.  Use https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/ to help.

Comment: This is wonderful! I now can figure out how to add to the BaseList using that page. But I still am not sure how to check the existing base list to see if it already inherits a class. Is it normal to rebuild the whole compilation unit? It seems like I had to traverse up until I had a MemberDeclarationSyntax so that I can have a root to get a node for an eventual replace. Is there no way to just replace the baseList, stick that in some thing so I can get the node from it for the replace? Updated Question.

Comment: You need the semantic model.

Answer (score 3):

For finding out if the class declaration inherits a class you can use:

```
if (classDeclaration.BaseList.Types.TryFirst(out var baseType) &&
    semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(baseType.Type).Symbol is ITypeSymbol type &&
    type.TypeKind == TypeKind.Class)
{
}
```

For adding a base type using `SyntaxGenerator` is probably easiest:

```
var updated = syntaxGenerator.AddBaseType(
    classDeclaration,
    SyntaxFactory.ParseName("Repository<User, UserTable>"));
```

The syntax generator does this for C#:

```
var updated = classDeclaration.WithBaseList(
    classDeclaration.BaseList.WithTypes(
        classDeclaration.BaseList.Types.Insert(
            0,
            SyntaxFactory.SimpleBaseType(SyntaxFactory.ParseName("Repository<User, UserTable>")))));
```

From [here](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/CodeGeneration/CSharpSyntaxGenerator.cs,3126) omitted check for empty list in the above.